# How to you setup ach transfers using stripe.net

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I know you have to create a customer and verify a bank account, but I'm not sure how to do the latter.

How do I go about verifying them on the customer?

To add a bank account to a customer, you need to create a token and add it to the sourceToken parameter since adding using the bank account services were not implement as of now.  For Example:

```
BankAccountCreateOptions bankAccount = new BankAccountCreateOptions();
    bankAccount.SourceBankAccount = new SourceBankAccount() {
    AccountHolderName = accountHolderName,
    AccountHolderType = "company",
    AccountNumber = bankAccountNumber,
    BankName = bankName,
    Country = "US",
    Currency = "usd",
    RoutingNumber = bankAccountRoutingNumber
};

// Setup the customer
StripeCustomerCreateOptions options = new   StripeCustomerCreateOptions();
    options.Email = email;
    options.Description = company;
    options.PlanId = plan.Id;
    options.TrialEnd = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1);
    options.SourceToken = bankAccount.SourceToken;

// Create the customer
StripeCustomer customer = new StripeCustomerService().Create(options);
```

However I still don't know how to verify the bank account once created.

Comment: Looks like this library does allow you to do so: https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net#verify-a-bank-account.

Comment: How about you read the question before commenting and downvoting.  I obviously looked at the documentation.

Comment: No it is not in the slightest bit obvious that you looked at the documentation.  If you had actually stated that you had, only then it would have been obvious.

Comment: How does calling out specific services in the documentation not point to that I looked at it...

Comment: did you figure this out? can you share the code?

Answer (score -1):

You can login to bank accounts by using test users in https://plaid.com/docs/api/#sandbox and register a user as stripe ACH. Create token by using test user bank details and create a customer for user.Do charges by using created customer id.